# Convert C++ function to C#

Tags: c#, c++, qt, porting

I am trying to port the following C++ function to C#:

```
QString Engine::FDigest(const QString & input)
{
    if(input.size() != 32) return "";

    int idx[] = {0xe, 0x3, 0x6, 0x8, 0x2},
        mul[] = {2, 2, 5, 4, 3},
        add[] = {0x0, 0xd, 0x10, 0xb, 0x5},
        a, m, i, t, v;

    QString b;
    char tmp[2] = { 0, 0 };

    for(int j = 0; j <= 4; j++)
    {
        a = add[j];
        m = mul[j];
        i = idx[j];

        tmp[0] = input[i].toAscii();
        t = a + (int)(strtol(tmp, NULL, 16));
        v = (int)(strtol(input.mid(t, 2).toLocal8Bit(), NULL, 16));

        snprintf(tmp, 2, "%x", (v * m) % 0x10);
        b += tmp;
    }

    return b;
}
```

Some of this code is easy to port however I'm having problems with this part:

```
tmp[0] = input[i].toAscii();
t = a + (int)(strtol(tmp, NULL, 16));
v = (int)(strtol(input.mid(t, 2).toLocal8Bit(), NULL, 16));

snprintf(tmp, 2, "%x", (v * m) % 0x10);
```

I have found that `(int)strtol(tmp, NULL, 16)` equals `int.Parse(tmp, "x")` in C# and `snprintf` is `String.Format`, however I'm not sure about the rest of it.

How can I port this fragment to C#?

Comment: Have updated my answer with potentially useful info

Comment: I'm assuming QString is a QT class?  I added the tag.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit** I have a suspicion that your code actually does a MD5 digest of the input data.
See below for a snippet based on that assumption.

### Translation steps

A few hints that should work well<sup>1</sup>

> **Q: `tmp[0] = input[i].toAscii();`**

```
bytes[] ascii = ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes(input);
tmp[0] = ascii[i];
```

> **Q: `t = a + (int)(strtol(tmp, NULL, 16));`**

```
t = a + int.Parse(string.Format("{0}{1}", tmp[0], tmp[1]),
               System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

> **Q: `v = (int)(strtol(input.mid(t, 2).toLocal8Bit(), NULL, 16));`**

No clue about the toLocal8bit, would need to read Qt documentation...

> **Q: `snprintf(tmp, 2, "%x", (v * m) % 0x10);`**

```
{
    string tmptext = ((v*m % 16)).ToString("X2");
    tmp[0] = tmptext[0];
    tmp[1] = tmptext[1];
}
```

### What if ... it's just MD5?

You could try this directly to see whether it achieves what you need:

```
using System;

public string FDigest(string input)
{
   MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
   byte[] ascii = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (input);
   byte[] hash  = md5.ComputeHash (ascii);

   // Convert the byte array to hexadecimal string
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
       sb.Append (hash[i].ToString ("X2")); // "x2" for lowercase
   return sb.ToString();
}
```

<sup>1</sup> explicitly not optimized, intended as quick hints; optimize as necessary

Comment: I added an md5 implementation using System.Security since I have a suspicion (after googling the original code) that it _might_ be MD5. Note: this is nothing more than a suspicion (I don't readily recognize the code for hash functions))

Comment: for sure its not MD5 since im computing MD5 before this function and input of this function is MD5 hash, but thanks for some hints.

Comment: Can we get rid of the tiny text please?

Answer (score 0):

A few more hints:

t is a two byte buffer and you only ever write to the first byte, leaving a trailing nul. So t is always a string of exactly one character, and you're processing a hex number one character at a time. So I think

```
tmp[0] = input[i].toAscii();
t = a + (int)(strtol(tmp, NULL, 16));
```

this is roughly `int t = a + Convert.ToInt32(input.substring(i, 1), 16);` - take one digit from input and add its hex value to a which you've looked up from a table. (I'm assuming that the toAscii is simply to map the QString character which is already a hex digit into ASCII for strtol, so if you have a string of hex digits already this is OK.)

Next

```
v = (int)(strtol(input.mid(t, 2).toLocal8Bit(), NULL, 16));
```

this means look up two characters from input from offset t, i.e. `input.substring(t, 2)`, then convert these to a hex integer again. `v = Convert.ToInt32(input.substring(t, 2), 16);` Now, as it happens, I think you'll only actually use the second digit here anyway since the calculation is `(v * a) % 0x10`, but hey. If again we're working with a QString of hex digits then toLocal8Bit ought to be the same conversion as toAscii - I'm not clear why your code has two different functions here.

Finally convert these values to a single digit in tmp, then append that to b

```
snprintf(tmp, 2, "%x", (v * m) % 0x10);
b += tmp;
```

(2 is the length of the buffer, and since we need a trailing nul only 1 is ever written) i.e.

```
int digit = (v * m) % 0x10;
b += digit.ToString("x");
```

should do. I'd personally write the mod 16 as a logical and, `& 0xf`, since it's intended to strip the value down to a single digit.

Note also that in your code `i` is never set - I guess that's a loop or something you omitted for brevity?

So, in summary

```
int t = a + Convert.ToInt32(input.substring(i, 1), 16);
int v = Convert.ToInt32(input.substring(t, 2), 16);
int nextDigit = (v * m) & 0xf;
b += nextDigit.ToString("x");
```